# How to find and run my old (global) version of Python?

Tags: python, installation

I have locally installed a newer version of Python. For that I did the following:

```
$ cd
$ mkdir opt
$ mkdir downloads
$ cd downloads
$ wget http://www.python.org/ftp/python/2.6.2/Python-2.6.2.tgz
$ tar xvzf Python-2.6.2.tgz
$ cd Python-2.6.2
$ ./configure --prefix=$HOME/opt/ --enable-unicode=ucs4
$ make
$ make install
```

In .bash_profile I put the following:

```
export PATH=$HOME/opt/bin/:$PATH
export PYTHONPATH=$HOME/opt/lib:$HOME/opt/lib/site-packages:$PYTHONPATH
```

And than I executed:

```
$ cd
$ source .bash_profile
$ python -V
```

It worked. I got a new working versions  of Python. However, now I would like to try something with my old version, which is a "global" version installed by root for all users. Can anybody, pleas, tell me how I can do it?

P.S.
I tired to remove changes in .bash_profile. I have commented the 2 last lines which were added when I installed the new version. So, now I have the following .bash_profile file:

```
# .bash_profile

# Get the aliases and functions
if [ -f ~/.bashrc ]; then
        . ~/.bashrc
fi

# User specific environment and startup programs

PATH=$PATH:$HOME/bin

export PATH

#export PATH=$HOME/opt/bin/:$PATH
#export PYTHONPATH=$HOME/opt/lib:$HOME/opt/lib/site-packages:$PYTHONPATH
```

And I source the new version of the file (source .bash_profile). But I still get the old version of Python. When I type "Python -V" I get "Python 2.6.2".

Comment: OK, I see. I am new here. But I will start to accept.

Comment: Notice that your .bashrc redefineds PATH by _adding_ to it. So, if your path already has your new directory, sourcing your .bashrc file will not remove the old path. To start fresh, just start a new shell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can directly call the program with something like "/usr/local/bin/python myscript.py". You just need to know where your standard installation of python is. If you don't know,  you can undo your changes and then type "which python" to find out what actually gets executed when you type "python" on the command line".

For example:

```
$ /usr/bin/python -V
Python 2.3.4
$ /usr/bin/python2.4 -V
Python 2.4.4
$ /opt/local/bin/python2.7 -V
Python 2.7a0
$ python -V
Python 2.5.2
$ which python
/usr/bin/python
```

To make things easier you can also create aliases:

```
$ alias python2.4=/usr/bin/python2.4
$ alias python2.5=/usr/bin/python2.5
$ python2.4 -V
Python 2.4.4
$ python2.5 -V
Python 2.5.2
```

Aliases make it pretty easy for you to run different versions of python. Place them in your .bashrc file so they are always defined.

Answer (score 0):

Undo your changes to `.bash_profile` and execute `source .bash_profile`.

Comment: I tried that. It did not work (I added more details in my original question).